# How to add column Date Shipped to Sales Order Grid magento

Tags: magento

I'm stuck with adding column to sales order grid from shipment grid. 
The problem is: "Purchased On" in DB has name "created_at", "Date Shipped" has also name "created_at", so when I join "created_at" from "sales_flat_shipment_grid" I see purchased on date only with name date shipped.
I'm using this code:
in _prepareCollection()

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfsg'=>'sales_flat_shipment_grid'),'sfsg.order_increment_id=main_table.increment_id',array('sfsg.created_at'));
```

and in _prepareColumns()

```
$this->addColumn('created_at', array(
           'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Date Shipped'),
           'index'     => 'created_at',
          'type'      => 'datetime',
          'filter_index'=>'sfsg.created_at',

       ));
```

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

After few hours of trying I've found answer in my case it is:
in _prepareCollection() add

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfsg'=>$resource->getTableName('sales_flat_shipment_grid')),'sfsg.order_increment_id=main_table.increment_id',array(
```

'shiped' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(sfsg.created_at SEPARATOR " | ")'),
));

and in _prepareColums()

```
$this->addColumn('shiped', array(
       'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Date Shipped'),
       'index'     => 'shiped',
      'type'      => 'datetime',
      'filter_index'=>'sfsg.created_at',
            ));
```